# Installer windows service using msi installer

Tags: c++, windows, windows-installer

I am new to the windows installer. I need an .msi installer for a windows service written in plain c++ (No .NET). I have heard that it is possible, but i don't know how.

Can somebody tell me how to get the installer to install my service? It needs to be an .msi isntaller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the WiX toolset you'd just add to the `Component` that contains the `File` that is the service executable:

```
<ServiceInstall Id="MyService" Name="MyService" DisplayName="My Cool Service" 
                Description="Description of my cool service." 
                Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I have the chance. Can you name a good tutorial on the WiX installer especially on my issue?

Comment: @Christopher Painter, the first file in the Component will be the KeyPath and ideally there is only the service executable in the Component so KeyPath attribute is not required.

Comment: @peer, you can find the WiX tutorial at http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/tutorial